# Mouse wheel scrolling stop suddenly on my website

Tags: css, scroll, mousewheel

I did not touch any jquery or js file I dont how to fix it now.
I try to remove `overflow: hidden` from `style.css` but it also did not work for me. I can't paste any code as I did not change any js. In console there is also no error showing. please help me . I try to search it on google but did not find any solution hope you guys can solve it for me.

```
body {
    color: #878787;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

This body code in `style.css`

Comment: Have you added any external js for scrolling? can you please share your website url?

Comment: lemme make it online wait bro

Comment: are you able to see the scrollbar on the page??

Comment: but i ddnt add any external js

Comment: yes i make a little change overflow: auto;

Comment: and scrollbar is showing

Comment: http://ital.esy.es/italstone/

Comment: here is the link of website

Comment: lol its working fine now in online wtf